# QSharedData crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qshareddata

I have an infrequent but fairly consistent crash in my Qt 5.2.0 application which I am having a heck of a time diagnosing, but believe to be related to `QSharedData`. The application is highly multi-threaded, which is presumably part of the problem.

The class in question is here:

```
class RouteData : public QSharedData
{
public:
  RouteData() :
      m_destAddress(0),
      m_valid(false),
      m_movingAverage(ROUTE_INITIAL_QUALITY)
  { }
  RouteData(const RouteData &other) :
      QSharedData(other),
      m_destAddress(other.m_destAddress),
      m_addresses(other.m_addresses),
      m_valid(other.m_valid),
      m_movingAverage(other.m_movingAverage),
      m_lastSuccess(other.m_lastSuccess),
      m_lastFailure(other.m_lastFailure)
  { }
  ~RouteData() { }

  quint16           m_destAddress;
  QList<quint16>    m_addresses;
  bool              m_valid;
  double            m_movingAverage;
  QDateTime         m_lastSuccess;
  QDateTime         m_lastFailure;
};

class Route
{
public:
    Route()
    {
        d = new RouteData;
    }
    Route(quint16 destAddress)
    {
        d = new RouteData;
        d->m_destAddress = destAddress;
    }
    Route(const Route &other) : d(other.d) {}

    QString toString() const;

    bool            isValid() const         { return d->m_valid; }
    quint16         destAddress() const     { return d->m_destAddress; }
    QList<quint16>  addressList() const     { return d->m_addresses; }
    quint32         length() const          { return d->m_addresses.length(); }
    double          quality() const         { return d->m_movingAverage; }
    quint64         msecsSinceLastFailure() const;

    void            setDestination(quint16 dest) { d->m_destAddress = dest; }
    void            setAddressList(const QList<quint16> &addressList);
    void            markResult(bool success);

    bool operator<(const Route& other) const;
    bool operator==(const Route& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Route& other) const;

private:
    QSharedDataPointer<RouteData> d;
};

Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(Route, Q_MOVABLE_TYPE);
```

The crash occurs here, inserting a Route into a `QMap`:

```
SendResult EmberGateway::ezspSendUnicast(quint16 indexOrDestination, ..., const Route& route)
{
...
    if (route.isValid()) {
        m_lastRouteMap.insert(indexOrDestination, route);
```

where m_lastRouteMap is a `QMap<quint16, Route>`.

And the stack trace looks like this:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fa297ced9a8 in QTimeZone::~QTimeZone() () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#1  0x00007fa297c96de5 in QDateTime::~QDateTime() () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00000000004644fb in RouteData::~RouteData (this=0x7fa28c00b150, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../libILS/libILS/Route.h:33
#3  0x0000000000600805 in QSharedDataPointer<RouteData>::operator= (this=0x7fa28c0e6420, o=...)
    at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/include/QtCore/qshareddata.h:98
#4  0x00000000005ff55b in Route::operator= (this=0x7fa28c0e6420) at ./libILS/Route.h:43
#5  0x0000000000652f8e in QMap<unsigned short, Route>::insert (this=0x7fa28c0880e8, akey=@0x7fa17c6feb44: 25504, avalue=...)
    at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/include/QtCore/qmap.h:682
#6  0x0000000000641b4b in ils::EmberGateway::ezspSendUnicast (this=0x7fa28c088090, indexOrDestination=25504, apsFrame=..., 
    data=..., route=...) at libILS/Gateways/EmberGateway.cpp:909
#7  0x00000000006371d5 in ils::EmberGateway::sendUnicast (this=0x7fa28c088090, destAddress=25504, array=..., route=...)
    at libILS/Gateways/EmberGateway.cpp:474
#8  0x00000000005fadc4 in NetworkController::sendMessageViaGateway (this=0x7fa28c03e9b0, message=...)
    at libILS/Controllers/NetworkController.cpp:1668
#9  0x00000000005ed8f4 in NetworkController::dispatchMessage (this=0x7fa28c03e9b0, pendingMessagePair=...)
    at libILS/Controllers/NetworkController.cpp:913
#10 0x0000000000604e2f in QtConcurrent::VoidStoredMemberFunctionPointerCall1<void, NetworkController, QPair<QSharedPointer<Message>, QTimer*>, QPair<QSharedPointer<Message>, QTimer*> >::runFunctor (this=0x7fa23804ac60)
    at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentstoredfunctioncall.h:410
#11 0x00000000005ff41e in QtConcurrent::RunFunctionTask<void>::run (this=0x7fa23804ac60)
    at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/include/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrunbase.h:132
#12 0x00007fa297c55e52 in ?? () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007fa297c591c2 in ?? () from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-5.2.0/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007fa297746f3a in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#15 0x00007fa296c698fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

So at #5 we're doing the QMap::insert, and at #4 creating a copy (via Route "=" operator). At #3 the Qt code in question looks like this:

```
inline QSharedDataPointer<T> & operator=(const QSharedDataPointer<T> &o) {
    if (o.d != d) {
        if (o.d)
            o.d->ref.ref();
        T *old = d;
        d = o.d;
        if (old && !old->ref.deref())
            delete old;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

We're hitting the "delete old" and seg faulting in the dtor for one of the `QDateTime`'s (actually it's private `QTimeZone` member).

My `ezspSendUnicast()` method can run fine for hundreds of thousands of iterations before crashing. I don't think I'm leaking memory (according to valgrind). I believe that the Route object I'm passing to ezspSendUnicast() is properly mutex protected, but it's possible I've missed something (but I thought the `QSharedData` was thread-safe for copy-on-write, in any case).

Any insight on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `QSharedData` is thread-safe, but `QMap` isn't. Have you properly guarded insert with locks?

Comment: @AlexTelishev `QSharedDataPointer` is thread-safe. That's it. The data it accesses doesn't magically become thread-safe, not at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instances of `QSharedData`, when accessed via a **separate instance** of `QSharedDataPointer`, can be, in fact, accessed from multiple threads at once, and it's safe. The shared data pointer will atomically take a copy of the referenced data, as needed.

So, as long as you're working on your own *instance* of the `Route` object, everything is fine. What you can't do is use a *reference* to an element held by a container. You can use a const-reference to a *temporary* object constructed from the one held by the container - that is, to a new instance.

Per the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-modules.html#threads-and-implicitly-shared-classes):

> Proper locking should be used when *sharing an instance* of an
>   implicitly shared class between threads.

It is **never correct** to access a reference to a *shared* instance of an implicitly shared class without holding the lock.

You must *always* have a new instance. You *can* copy construct a temporary instance and then pass it via a const reference, for example as an argument in a function call. [Such const-references-to-temporary-instances delay the destruction of the referenced temporary object until they are not needed anymore](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

**This applies to all implicitly shared classes in Qt 4 and Qt 5** -- whether coming from Qt proper (all containers!), or of your own design that leverages `QSharedDataPointer`.

So, this would be correct - you keep your own instance.

```
Route r(...);
QMutexLocker l(&routeMapMutex);
routeMap.insert(key, r);
l.unlock();
r.setDestination(...);
QMutexLocker l(&routeMapMutex);
routeMap.insert(key, r);
l.unlock();
```

As is this - again, you have your own instance.

```
QMutexLocker l(&routeMapMutex);
Route r = routeMap[key];
l.unlock();
if (r.isValid()) ...
```

But this is certainly incorrect, even though the reference is const.

```
QMutexLocker l(&routeMapMutex);
const Route & r = routeMap[key];
l.unlock();
if (r.isValid()) ...
```

But this is correct, since it is a const reference to a temporary instance, whose lifetime is prolonged as needed. So, you reference a new instance that nobody but you have access to.

```
QMutexLocker l(&routeMapMutex);
const Route & r = Route(routeMap[key]);
l.unlock();
if (r.isValid()) ...
```

This is also correct, since the call is guarded by the mutex:

```
void fun(const Route &);
QMutexLocker l(&routeMapMutex);
fun(routeMap[key]);
l.unlock();
```

My hunch is that somewhere in your code you access the reference to the value in the map (as opposed to a const-ref to a temporary) without holding the mutex.

It's also conceivable that you are having some other memory or threading bug that manifests itself in an unrelated place.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I think what's going on is this: I have a mutable container of Routes accessed by multiple threads, let's say `QList<Route> m_routeList`. It's always accessed inside a mutex lock `m_routeMutex`. My crashing method does something like `m_routeMutex.lock(); Route r = getRoute(m_routeList); m_routeMutex.unlock()`. My assumption at this point was I can now do anything (read-only in my case) I want with `r` because if another thread mucked with its "parent" in m_routeList my r instance would automatically be detached.

Comment: (cont) This appears to not be the case, so when I do the `QMap::insert(r)` my thread tries to detach r, but the parent has already been deleted so seg fault from the second delete. But why? Shouldn't my r have kept the ref count positive? I suppose I could explicitly detach r inside the mutex (by adding a method to the Route class), but that seems kind of hacky. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed explanation and examples. Your hunch was correct, my error stemmed from my misunderstanding of the behavior of reference versus const-ref.